# Bitmap size greater than width and height

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

There is an image (PNG) i am trying to load to an ImageView. 
The file size of this PNG file is 390.6KB.

Once i decode this PNG file to a bitmap, the bitmap size is >9MB. 
But the bitmap's width and height is 1920 and 1280 respectively.

Why is the size of bitmap > ( bitmap.width * bitmap.height )? 
9MB is a lot for my app, which loads many other images like this.

When i try to sample this image by giving the sample size (2/4), the width and height of the image changes along with the size of the bitmap.

How do i scale this image in memory size, but preserve width and height of the image?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. Scaled down your image.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, i have tried scaling the image down using inSampleSize of 2 & 4, this did reduce the memory size of the image, but at the same time reduced the width/height of the image from 1920/1280 to 960/640. Which is not desired.

Comment: I would like to understand why is the memory size of the bitmap greater than (bitmap.width * bitmap.height). As I would imagine, there is no compression here.

Comment: have you read the post in the link completely. The docs under Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory has few pints worth noting. For example, it’s not worth loading a 1024x768 pixel image into memory if it will eventually be displayed in a 128x96 pixel thumbnail in an ImageView.

Comment: If you are drawing the bitmap on a canvas you can do  canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null); where matrix is a scaled matrix. e.g. matrix.postScale(xScale, yScale);

Comment: @Raghunandan I would indeed like to load this image to 1920/1280 view. This is the background image for the application. After doing the sampling, the 960/640 image looked a little crappy when displayed on a 1080p screen.

Comment: @Shagan whats your imageview width and height?? or Layout width and height for which you set background?

Comment: @Raghunandan width = 1920, height = 1280

Comment: @Shagan is your view for which you set background is 1920 cross 1280 ?

Comment: yes. and 9MB memory size for this image alone is a lot for my app.

Comment: What device has that resolution? You should be sizing that image to the appropriate size depending on the device. Generally, devices with bigger screens have more memory so you should be good if you actually need that resolution, but you can't expect to use that image on every device at that resolution.

Answer (score 5):

A PNG can have upto 4 channels (ARGB), so your actual memory consumption will be `width*height*4` as each pixel requires 4 spaces in memory.

You can do a similar calculation for pretty much any other image format: `width*height*channels`

Comment: Yes, for a PNG file. But, why is the bitmap memory size > (bitmap.width * bitmap.height)?

Comment: Okay.. maybe its my misunderstanding.. the size of the file is 9 MB == 1920 * 1280 * 4 ?

Comment: @Shagan The number of channels matter. [(1920*1280*4)/(1024*1024) = 9.3MB](https://www.google.com/search?q=(1920+*+1280+*+4)%2F(1024*1024)&aq=f&oq=(1920+*+1280+*+4)%2F(1024*1024))